# Why PEAR Math_BigInteger(48) => 0?  (case : MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE => default)

Tags: php, math, pear

I used PEAR/Math/BigInteger.php

1. PHP 5.2.5 (cli)
2. ubuntu

but

```
$a = new Math_BigInteger(48);
echo $a -> toString()// '0'
```

Why?
is it a bug?

it is specific of `MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE => default`

> 3528     function _int2bytes($x)
>
> pack('N', 48) => 0

we need

> if('48'===(string)$x){$this->value=array('48');return;}

Comment: Works fine for me, what OS, version of PHP etc are you using?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary unless you're running a 4.x version of PHP, but what happens if you try echo $a->toString(); ?

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger and stepping through to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on a i686 system:

```
$ php -r 'require_once "Math/BigInteger.php"; $a = new Math_BigInteger(48); echo $a -> toString();'
48
```